# How to estimate individual repeatability of a trait (intraclass correlational coefficient) in a data set of many species in R?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I need to estimate individual repeatability (R, intraclass correlation coefficient) of a trait in a multispecies dataset (35 species). There only few individuals with repeated measurements within each species and 2-4 repeated measurements per each individual, so I cannot evaluate R within each species. The trait is highly dependent of body mass, so I must include it in the model as covariate. Since there are some differences between species in trait that cannot be explained by body weight, I need to consider species affiliation. What is the best way to do this? Does it make sense just to include species affiliation in the LMM model as a second random term to take it into account, e.g. using 'lmer' function from lm4 package or, more convenient, using ‘rptGaussian’ function from rptR package ("ID" is code of individuals, "Species" is species name):

`rptGaussian(Trait ~ BodyMass + (1|ID) + (1|Species), grname=c("ID", "Species", "Fixed"), data=repeatability, nboot=1000, npermut=1000)`

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Thank you, MrFlick! I will repeat my questuion there.